# Problems with deepCopy/cloning of 4D array

Tags: java, clone, deep-copy

I am trying to deep copy a 4d int array as the solution of my algorithm. Unfortunately, when I call that solution at the end of my program, it is not the one that was supposed to be deepcopied. It is also neither the first nor the last created solution. I figure the problem must lie in deepCopy as cloning the same solution in a 1d array works fine.

I am trying to deepcopy w[][][][]:

```
public Object clone()
{   
    MySolution copy = (MySolution)super.clone();
    copy.w = deepCopyOf(w);
    copy.wtour = (int[])this.wtour.clone();

    return copy;
}   // end clone

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T[] deepCopyOf(T[] array) {

    if (0 >= array.length) return array;

    return (T[]) deepCopyOf(
            array, 
            Array.newInstance(array[0].getClass(), array.length), 
            0);
}

private static Object deepCopyOf(Object array, Object copiedArray, int index) {

    if (index >= Array.getLength(array)) return copiedArray;

    Object element = Array.get(array, index);

    if (element.getClass().isArray()) {

        Array.set(copiedArray, index, deepCopyOf(
                element,
                Array.newInstance(
                        element.getClass().getComponentType(),
                        Array.getLength(element)),
                0));
    } 
    else {
        Array.set(copiedArray, index, element);
    }
    return deepCopyOf(array, copiedArray, ++index);
}
```

I am using the openTS Tabu Search framework by Harder and the fact that the wtour array gets copied just fine shows me that there must be something wrong with the deepcopy method for w[][][][]

EDIT:  novic3 assumed that I have to iterate over the different array levels. I tried doing the following which is a little bit different in its approach. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work.

```
public static int[][][][] deepCopy2(int[][][][] original) {
    if (original == null) {
        return null;
    }

    final int[][][][] result = new int[original.length][original[0].length][original.length+1][];
    for (int i = 0; i < original.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < original.length; j++) {
            for (int q= 0; q <= original.length; q++) {
                result[i][j][q] = Arrays.copyOf(original[i][j][q], original[i][j][q].length);

                // For Java versions prior to Java 6 use the next:
                //System.arraycopy(original[i], 0, result[i], 0, original[i].length);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I think you'll also need methods like `<T> T[][] deepCopyOf(T[][] array)`,  `<T> T[][][] deepCopyOf(T[][][] array)` and  `<T> T[][][][] deepCopyOf(T[][][][] array)`. Your code would work fine for 1d array. You should first try deepCopy of T[][].

Comment: Thanks novic. I changed my entry. Unfortunately, it does not work. DO you have anyy assumptions what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
public int[] deepCopy(int[] w) {
    int[] ans = new int[w.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < w.length; i++) {
        ans[i] = w[i];
    }
    return ans;
}

public int[][] deepCopy2(int[][] w) {
    int[][] ans = new int[w.length][];
    for (int i = 0; i < w.length; i++) {
        ans[i] = deepCopy(w[i]);
    }
    return ans;
}

public int[][][] deepCopy3(int[][][] w) {
    int[][][] ans = new int[w.length][][];
    for (int i = 0; i < w.length; i++) {
        ans[i] = deepCopy2(w[i]);
    }
    return ans;
}

public int[][][][] deepCopy4(int[][][][] w) {
    int[][][][] ans = new int[w.length][][][];
    for (int i = 0; i < w.length; i++) {
        ans[i] = deepCopy3(w[i]);
    }
    return ans;
}
```

To use, call `deepCopy4(w)`

Comment: Thanks novic! unfortunately, the result is the same as by using my first first deepcopy method. It changes when I switch my decision variable from static to non static though. May that be the problem?

Comment: Changing it from static to non-static will change behaviour only if you're accessing static variable from somewhere else. So it could be one of the reasons. The issue could be in the way clone() is being used. I tested the deepCopy4 method and it works IMO.